# Oracle .dmp of files

Tags: oracle, dmp, oracle-dump

I have received a file named STP.dmp containing a database backup, which I have successfully restored into Oracle.

I have also received multiple additional .dmp files, named sequentially - eg. STP-DOCS01.dmp, STP-DOCS02.dmp - which I am expecting to contain image and document files (perhaps in blob data format, I don't know).

However, upon trying to restore this database, using the following command:

```
Impdp bkup_user/password directory=exp_table dumpfile=STP_DOCS01.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE
```

I get an error: *cannot location master table within provided dump files*. I get the same when I try to get the database schema. The third-party who provided the files swear that the DOCS backup completed correctly and that they've sent us all the files.

I've tried renaming the DOCS DMP files so the name is in line with the main database, in case they were part of the same database, but that didn't do anything. I'm completely out of ideas what else to try. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are sequentially named it could mean that the person which have done the exports used parallelism and wrote to multiple files at once, this is why a single file doesn't have a complete part of the data, try importing using:

```
Impdp bkup_user/password directory=exp_table dumpfile=STP_DOCS%U.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE
```